# How to redirect to view in mvc4 in ext.net in button click (the url has culture)

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, ext.net

I am working with Ext.net with mvc 4 .I cant redirect to a view and i am using globilization

my route config file is

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{                     
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");                      

    routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Default",
        url: "{culture}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new
        {
            culture = CultureHelper.GetDefaultCulture(), 
            controller = "Registration", 
            action = "Login", 
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        });                   
}
```

My controller is:

```
public ActionResult Test()
{
    return View();
}
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

I have both views for those actions.

My Test View has one button

```
@(X.Button().DirectEvents(de => { de.Click.Url = "Index"; }))
```

If i click that button it goes to controller side of Index And also to the view side but the view page is not displaying.. But if i use Scripts it directs properly to the view

```
@(X.Button()..OnClientClick("redirect "))
```

And my script is

```
<script>
    var redirect = function () {
        window.location.href = ' @Url.Action("Index", "Default1") ';
    }
</script>
```

What should i do to redirect to the view and view should be displayed..
One more think i followed this link to create globilization http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

To redirect during a DirectEvent you can do the following:

View

```
@X.Button().DirectClickAction("DirectEventAction")
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult DirectEventAction()
{
    return this.Redirect(Url.Action("Index"));
}
```